# How to implement touch feedback like Android Kitkat search?

Tags: android, android-animation, touch-event

Android Kitkat has a really nice touch feedback for the search bar. I need to implement similar feedback, but for the ViewGroup.

I've written this code for the tests:

```
public class CircleLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    float x, y;
    boolean handled = false;
    Paint paint;

    public CircleLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint  = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0x44FFFFFF);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(handled) {
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 50, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        if(!handled) {
            handled = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            handled = false;
        }
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

It works, but only if the child View is not intercepts touch events. So, my first question is - how to handle all touch events and do not intercept them for the child views.

And I want to add some fade effect for the circle after finger up. Using by `ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(View)` and `paint.setOpacity(int)`, yes, but where to start it and and what condition use for finish? System time after last down event or there is another solution?

[image: Search bar in the Kitkat]